# How to publish nuget prerelease version package

Tags: package, nuget, pack

I understand how to publish a nuget package using nuget command line

[nuget command line](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference)

But I Have searched around I don't find docs about how to publish a nuget prerelease package

[image]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You only need to specify a version string that uses SemVer format (e.g. 1.0-beta) instead of the usual format (e.g. 1.0) and NuGet will automatically treat it as a prerelease package.

"As of NuGet 1.6, NuGet supports the creation of prerelease packages by specifying a prerelease string in the version number according to the Semantic Versioning (SemVer) specification."
[See NuGetDocs - Prerelease Versions](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/prerelease-packages)

Comment: I tried `--version-suffix beta` flag when using `dotnet pack` and it doesn't seem to consider it a prerelease

Answer (score 28):

Also, prerelease version don't show up if their version number is lower than the stable version. For example if you have

- MyNuget v1.0.26
- MyNuget v1.0.25-beta

Only the stable version will appear in the list.

If you have

- MyNuget v1.0.26
- MyNuget v1.**1**.25-beta

The Prerelease version will be installable.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add "-alpha" or "-beta" to `version` key of your `.nuspec` file. This will publish your client as prerelease version.

Important Tip: Suppose, you want to test a version `7.6.6.4`, then you can add -alpha in `7.6.6.4-alpha`. Avoid adding `-alpha` to your already published version, like: `7.6.6.3-alpha`

**Sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>AnalyticalService.Client</id>
    <version>7.6.6.4-alpha</version>
    <title>.net client for Analytical Service</title>
    <authors>Kushal Seth</authors>
    <owners>Kushal Seth</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Alpha version for events integration</description>
    <summary>Alpha version for events integration</summary>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" />
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" />
      <dependency id="System.Net.Http" version="4.0.0" />
      <dependency id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3" />
      <dependency id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.3.3" />
      <dependency id="Polly" version="7.1.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" />
      <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="E:\service\AnalyticalService\src\AnalyticalService.Client\bin\Release\AnalyticalService.Client.dll" target="lib\AnalyticalService.Client.dll" />
    <file src="E:\service\AnalyticalService\src\AnalyticalService.Client\bin\Release\AnalyticalService.Model.dll" target="lib\AnalyticalService.Model.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

To check your published package in Nuget Package Manager, you must select this checkbox: (I am using VS 2019 Professtional 16.8 version, you may have similar option in your VS version)

[image]